# Amplifier Help for 8 ohm speaker

Tags: amplifier

How can I get 225mA of current from a 5Vpp sine wave at 150Hz using BJT's? I've been playing around with common emitter's and emitter followers but havent been able to get a high current output.

Comment: Use a power transistor? Too vague and too broad.

Comment: Please show your power supplies. Also, are you trying to do this entirely with discrete transistors, or are you willing to add an op amp to the mix?

Comment: @EJP Can a general purpose BJT output current that high though an 8 ohm 0.2W speaker? like the 2N3904 BJT

Comment: I'm open to adding an opamp to the mix. I wanted to use only BJT's but i've been stuck on this for awhile now.

Comment: Use a transistor rated for Ic>225mA. If the input is 5Vp-p then use an emitter follower. Post the circuit you're trying so far if you want more help.

Comment: With an opamp, let it drive an emitter follower.

Answer (score 1):

**THE FIRST CUT:**

The short answer is "You can't", since 5 VPP equals about 1.77 volts RMS and  the most current you can push through an 8 ohm load with that voltage across it is:

$$I=\frac{E}{R}= \frac{1.77V}{8\Omega}= 0.221 \ amperes, $$

and that's not even considering transistor losses.

**SLICING A LITTLE FINER,**

Since you have an 8 ohm loudspeaker which is rated to dissipate 0.2 watts and, since

$$ P =\ I^2R, $$

we can rearrange that relationship to solve for the current needed to get that power like this:

$$ I=\sqrt{\frac{P}{R}}=\sqrt{\frac{0.2W}{8\Omega}}= 0.025\ amperes $$

Then, since we need to relate that to the voltage required for that charge to flow, we can say

$$E=IR= 0.025A\times  8\Omega = 0.2V  $$

So, it looks like you've got a lot of wiggle room.

Comment: I can add a voltage divider to add a dc offset to the input signal to fix that right?

Comment: @EE_Eric No, of course not. You can't 'fix' Ohm's law. You need a minimum of 5.09VPP not counting transistor losses.